# How to Fix adding a User to a Group using Django REST framework(API)

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to build a savings API where A user can get the list of groups available and join the group as long as it as not exceeded the maximum number of members. I've tried a series of approach but it seems not to work, anytime I try to add a user to a group, it seems like it trying to add the whole user properties.

I made a group model and connected it to the user model via a ManytoMany field since a user can join many groups and a group can house many users. Where my problem lies in the serializer, any time I try to add a user

groups.model

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    group_id = models.UUIDField(default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False)
    max_no_members = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    savings_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    savings_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10, default = 'Monthly')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    begin_date = models.DateField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    searchable = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='group_members')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete 
    =models.CASCADE,related_name='group_admin' )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

groups.serializer

```
#List of Memebers
class GroupMembersListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # users = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Groups
        fields = ['members','name']

#Join a Group
class JoinGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users_to_join = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only = True, source = 
    'User')
    class Meta:
        model = Groups
        fields = ['members','users_to_join']
```

groups.views

```
#Create Group
class GroupCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Groups.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by= self.request.user, members = 
        [self.request.user])
#Members list Group
class GroupMembersList(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Groups.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupMembersListSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

#Join Group
class GroupJoinAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = 
    Groups.objects.annotate(arr=ArrayAgg('members')).values_list('id', 'arr')
    serializer_class = JoinGroupSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print(sys.stderr, self.queryset)
        if self.request.user.id in self.queryset.all():
            return 'User already in the group'
        else:
            list(self.queryset.all()).append(self.request.user.id)
            serializer.save()
```